# TRACK & PROPFIND HTTP Requests - Possible attack?

Tags: php, laravel, security, laravel-4, bugsnag

I have a laravel application and am using bugsnag for my error detection and received notification of 2 MethodNotAllowedHttpException's recently for the above request types.

I read online that TRACK requests are often used in attacks?

Both requests originated from the same IP in Turkey

As Laravel threw an Exception I'm assuming that no response would have been returned to the attacked with potentially compromising info?

Sorry if this is too vague to provide an answer but I don't really know much about website security

Comment: Nothing to worry about, your site will be vetted a thousand times over in more ways than this in the future.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply